# Pushing elements of a multidimensional array into another one in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have these arrays of arrays :

```
array0 = [["1"], ["2"], ["3"],…]

array1 = [["a"], ["b"], ["c"],…]

array2 = [["pap"], ["pop"], ["pip"],…]
```

I want to push every element in every array, to the first array so the output should be:

```
output = [["1", "a", "pap"], ["2", "b", "pop"], ["3", "c" ,"pip"]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First do `flatten` on each array to get single dimension array. Then use `zip` to get 2-dimension array each having 3-elements

```
array0.flatten.zip(array1.flatten, array2.flatten)
```

Shorter way of doing the same: (Solution given by @Ivaylo Strandjev)

```
array0.zip(array1, array2).map(&:flatten)
```

Comment: +1 Never noticed I should flatten the result. Still you can do it in a shorter manner, take a look at my answer.

Comment: @Mehdi Kumar `Ivaylo Strandjev` solution is good.. Use that :)

Comment: @checkit Thanks that helped a lot. I actually meant to make it 2-dimensional because I thought it will be more easier with it. But I see that I don't need that. an `a.zip()` will do the job. Thank you

Comment: @checkit thank you but in fact you were the first one to provide a **working** solution. So you deserve the accept. Still maybe edit your answer to suggest the shorter version for future generations.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 array0.zip(array1).zip(array2).map(&:flatten)
```

Also you can do it with a single `zip`:

```
 array0.zip(array1, array2).map(&:flatten)
```